# How to diagnose slow rails / rake / rspec tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake, rakefile

I always have a significant delay (c.10 seconds) when running tasks like:

- rails server
- rake assets:precompile
- rspec spec

The delay is at the point before it says:

```
    Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I've found several articles identifying 10 or more different parameters that can be tuned to speed up rake and / or rspec runs. But I'm reluctant to start fiddling around with 10 different parameters without a better understanding of what's causing it.

Is there way to diagnose what's causing that delay? Like something more verbose?

Supplementary info:
Ubuntu 14
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637660/how-do-i-debug-a-slow-rails-app-boot-time

Comment: Which database manager are you using?

Comment: @MaxWilliams thanks for that link, I'll look through the responses in that post. It MAY be a duplicate, but I note there was no accepted answer and it's also over 4 years old.

Comment: @MarcoPrins you mean like the adapter? postgresql

Comment: Yeah, i thought it would be a good source of leads at least...

Comment: @MaxWilliams thx. I'll update here if any of them pan out.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Mark Ellul's answer re: bumbler was actually quite cool (https://github.com/mark-ellul/Bumbler). I'm going to play around with that some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MaxWilliams for the link to this post [How do I debug a slow rails app boot time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637660/how-do-i-debug-a-slow-rails-app-boot-time)

I started using Mark Ellul's Bumbler - http://github.com/mark-ellul/Bumbler

It gave me exactly what I wanted - an insight into what's going in the background and which gems are taking the time. Of course I still need to speed up the slow ones (fog and authlogic seem to be two of the main culprits). But that's at different question.